# NDK: Android.mk / GNU Make

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

The Android.mk for my NDK project contains several hundred CPP files from which I build about a dozen static libs and finally a single shared lib. Most of my developing experience so far is on Windows, so I'm not very familiar with Linux, GNU Make, and the like.

When I add a new CPP file to Android.mk (i.e. to LOCAL_SRC_FILES), issuing ndk-build rebuilds all of my files, apparently because Android.mk changed, and it refers to all of the CPP files. Is there a way to avoid this? Let's assume I make a separate file for each static lib, and each such file would add that lib's CPP files to LOCAL_SRC_FILES and be included by Android.mk. Should that result in rebuilding only the lib whose included file is modified? This was actually my first attempt, but I went seriously wrong somewhere, and had to start over as the build would no longer succeed (which is why I'm asking before trying again).

Assuming the above approach is reasonable, how does including a file relate to the scope/lifetime of variables set in the including/included files?

Still hoping someone can answer this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328345/android-ndk-incremental-build

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try to split your project into **multiple android.mk files**, instead of *just one*. It would limit the recompilation step each time you change one of them.
Then try this `ndk-build -o <your_android.mk>`. For instance:

```
ndk-build -o jni/Android.mk
```

Ref: [How to prevent Android native project full rebuild after changing Android.mk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351830/how-to-prevent-android-native-project-full-rebuild-after-changing-android-mk)