# How to prevent Android native project full rebuild after changing Android.mk?

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I'm editing Android.mk of my project to fine-tune some compiler options. Every time the build process is started from scratch. I don't want to do a full rebuild after each and every change. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU `make` has the option `-o` (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?make) to do not remake the file file even if it is older than its dependencies,  and  do  not remake anything on account of changes in file. Essentially the file is treated as very  old  and  its  rules  are ignored.

This code does the trick:

```
ndk-build -o jni/Android.mk
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried -o and even --assume-old=. Something that is working is copying the Android.mk file before the change and then doing `touch -r Androind.mk_copy Android.mk`. How does that make any sense?