# How to Incremental compilation in NDK?

Tags: compilation, android-ndk

I have many cpp files in my android.mk,every times I add a cpp to Android.mk,it compiles all cpp,it's a lot of wasting time,so I need a way to Incremental compile.

Comment: The solution is to write your own makefile:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328345/android-ndk-incremental-build