# ndk-build keeps rebuilding all sources

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have set up Eclipse to build my C/C++ files. I created a builder and set it to point at 
the ndk-build executable in the ndk install tree. Each time I run this it keeps rebuilding all sources. I am not passing any arguments so why would it do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible to currently perform *incremental* builds using stock `android-ndk`. You *could*, however, do it manually. It's quite an involved process because you'll have to redo the makefiles and such. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4328345/1101070) answer for a description of what this involves.